# Creating a folder with username using PHP

Tags: php, mkdir

I think this may sound very straight forward, but still something is not working out. I am trying to create a folder with the name which is posted by the user and create a folder in the same directory. But I am not able to create one.

Here is my code:

```
$Name = $_POST['name'];     

$thisdir = getcwd(); 

$folderPath = $thisdir . '\\' . $Name;

mkdir($folderPath);

chmod($folderPath, 0777);
```

What can be the problem, where am I making mistake or is the problem lying with server settings. If so what should be done to change the PHP server settings

Thanks

Comment: Please tell us your problem. Error message?

Comment: You do realise that someone might enter their username as ../../../../../../../../../../../etc/passwd right?

Comment: ***WHAT ERROR MESSAGE DO YOU GET? Did you enable `display_errors` setting in php.ini?***

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest the following:

1. Check that you are getting data from $_POST using 'name' as the key.
2. Use '/' instead of '\' in the file path
3. Check you have permissions to create the directory in the current working directory (YOU may have, but does the webserver?)

Comment: And I recommend sanitizing the input before using it to create filenames

Answer (score 1):

remove other character from username and keep only a-z, 0-9,-_

You can remove these by 
str_replace(array("/","%"),array(),$_POST['name'])